# Transparent AppBarLayout Toolbar and placing content behind them

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

So far I've managed to implement AppBarLayout and Toolbar with scroll flags and AppBar scrolling behavior and it all works great. My final goal is to implement something like this:

[Netflix App Example](https://gfycat.com/optimaltalkativekronosaurus)

As you can see AppBar is transparent and the content is behind it. And everything else works perfectly.

From my observations when I put app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" (In my case I used app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior") tag CoordinatorLayout does not let me overlap Views (In this case AppBar should overlap my content).

This is my XML:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/root_nav_graph"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                />

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$Behavior"
            >

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"                  
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The fragment holds layout with NestedScrollView as a Root.

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution?

Comment: No I didn't unfortunately. I gave up on this as I couldn't spend any more hours on this problem for a project. I hope someone finds a solution. Also, most possibly custom layout behavior class is needed for this.

Comment: I'm looking for something like this too. Any idea on that?

Comment: I will do something like this in my next project, I will keep you posted on how that goes :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the attribute

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

from the Frame Layout. Also, set the attribute `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to your toolbar.